# Spring Bean injection not working Dwr

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, dwr

I have two actions in two different packages

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default json-default" namespace="/">

      <action name="getstarted"  class="GetStartedActionBean">
            <result name="success">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/jsp/getStarted.jsp</result>
      </action>
</package> 

<package name="example" extends="json-default">

      <action name="searchIndustryaction"  class="GetStartedActionBean"  method="searchIndustry">
      </action>

  </package>
```

I have injected one bean it is working fine when the page loads but my search is through dwr at that time bean is not injected

in my impl

```
private SessionFactory sessionfactory;

 public void setSessionfactory(SessionFactory sessionfactory) {
     this.sessionfactory = sessionfactory;
}
```

`sessionFactory` is set when the execute method is called but using dwr when i called `searchIndustry` `sessionfactory` is always null

Dwr entry

```
<create creator="new" javascript="AdvancedSearch" scope="application">
            <param name="class" value="com.sample.dao.impl.IndustryDAOImpl"/>        
        </create>
```

How would I call the injected bean in dwr?

Comment: where is your dwr.xml?

Comment: How is your bean being injected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DWR means you have to put an entry like this

```
<create creator="spring" javascript="Industry">
<param name="beanName" value="Yourbeanname" />
</create>
```

but you are directly calling the class so change to this format. Hope it may useful for you

Answer (score 0):

In your dwr.xml you can make for the creator one of those :

**new**: Which uses the Java 'new' operator.

**static**: Which uses the 'getInstance()' method (by default) to obtain an instance of the class.

**none**: This does not create objects. See below for why. (v1.1+)

**scripted**: Uses a scripting language like BeanShell or Groovy via BSF.

**spring**: Gives access to beans through the Spring Framework.

**jsf**: Uses objects from JSF. (v1.1+)

**struts**: Uses struts FormBeans. (v1.1+)

**pageflow**: Gives access to a PageFlow from Beehive or Weblogic. (v1.1+)